# Why wont it recognize the clicks in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I run my website in brackets (the HTML writing software) it recognizes the clicks on the DIVS but when I run it normally it won't.

Any help would be appreciated. I think it might be because brackets hosts it on a local server whereas it isn't hosted if not.

Comment: Please include your code in the question, or create a demo on a site like http://jsfiddle.net  No one is gonna download that mediafire link.

Comment: you need the local video files and things though otherwise i would have sorry @RocketHazmat this is the code though http://jsfiddle.net/uvmkvk87/

Comment: Change your `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your Brackets software is automatically referencing jQuery.

Make sure you have a reference to jQuery in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Change `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready` as mentioned by chazsolo.